# SQL Server select results as string separated with ','

Tags: sql-server

I have a `select` query that returns one column and I want to convert that to string rows separated  with ','

```
Select name 
from tblUsers
```

Gives a result:

```
Row1; asieh
Row2:amir
Row3:safoora
```

I want to return

```
Row1: asieh,amir,safoora
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91bec/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblUsers
    ([name] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO tblUsers
    ([name])
VALUES
    ('asieh'),
    ('amir'),
    ('safoora')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT STUFF((
        select ','+ name 
        from tblUsers
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        ,1,1,'') AS names
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91bec/1/0)**:

```
|              NAMES |
|--------------------|
| asieh,amir,safoora |
```

Answer (score 18):

Here's a solution using variables:

```
DECLARE @out VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @out = COALESCE(@out+',' ,'') + name
FROM tblUsers
SELECT @lout
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Create Table #tblUsers ( Name Varchar(100) );
Insert Into #tblUsers Values ('Row1; asieh'),('Row2:amir'),('Row3:safoora')

Select Stuff((Select ',' + Name
                From #tblUsers
                 For Xml Path('')
       ), 1, 1, '' ) As ConcatenedString

drop table #tblUsers
```